# Can I use an alias to replace much content in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

I want to write a table which may contain much content like this:

```
|foo|bar|
|---|---|
|foooooooooooooooo..much..content|bar_content|
```

So I wonder if I can use a alias/variable to replace the content, like:

```
|foo|bar|
|---|---|
|alias|bar_content|
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Markdown itself doesn't support variables, though some implementations / extensions might. Which Markdown processor are you using?

Comment: @Chris The Gitlab's. But I didn't find that.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with GitLab.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, it seems.